# "I'll call round and see you on my way home." Can we replace 'round' with 'around'?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

> "I'll call round and see you on my way home."

Can we replace 'round' with 'around'?

The question is: If I change to 'call around', does it still mean 'visit for a moment'?

In English, 'around' and 'round' go exchangeably together, but dictionaries say 'call around' means 'make several phone calls'.

> The earth goes round / around the sun.
> They live round / around the corner.
> We travelled round / around India.
> She turned round / around when I came in.

My dictionary says these are both acceptable in BrE. But "around" is possible only in AmE. The dictionary says "around" is more formal.

**CALL AROUND**
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/call-around
Definition of 'call around'
call around
REGIONAL NOTE:
in BRIT, usually use ring round
PHRASAL VERB
If you call around, you phone several people, usually when you are trying to organize something or to find some information.
[mainly US]
Call around to find the best bargains.

https://onlineteachersuk.com/phrasal-verbs-call/
Call around 1. visit 2. make phone callls

**CALL ROUND**
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_round
call round : To pay a short visit.
I'll call round later to pick up my prescription.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-round
I called round yesterday, but you weren’t in.

If it's not interchangeable, it's totally different and English learners must pay attention to the usage.

PS. I feel In BrE, "call around" has two meanings 1. visit 2. make phone calls and in AmE "call around" is making phone calls and both in BrE and AmE "call round" is visit.

Comment: What gave you the idea that “around” and “round” are interchangeable? Maybe you’ve confused it with ‘round, which is a contraction of around that is sometimes used in informal speech.

Comment: @ColleenV I was looking this up only yesterday in connection with another question.  See  the [Collins definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/round). Merriam-Webster gives one of its definitions of _round_ as 'same as AROUND'. It is never written with an apostrophe in British English.

Comment: Brandon - One of the Collins definitions of _round_ is _If you go round to someone's house, you visit them. Call_ can be used instead of _go. Call around_ is not idiomatic with this meaning.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks! That's the sort of information I was trying to elicit from the author. It belongs in the question.

Comment: The earth goes round / around the sun. They live round / around the corner. We travelled round / around India. She turned round / around when I came in.—My dictionary says these are both acceptable in BrE. But around is possible only in AmE. The dictionary says around is more formal.

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer puts **call around** as a more popular expression than **call round** (although this might include such contexts as **to call around 3 p.m.). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+round%2Ccall+around&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccall%20round%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccall%20around%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Ronald 'call around' means 'make a number of phone calls' and 'call round' means 'visit for a short time'.

Comment: Looking at Ronald's results for _call around_, I did find a few where it had been used in the sense of 'pay a visit', though many are references to making a phone call _around_ a certain time, or being on call _around the clock_, for example.

Comment: @Brandon The distinction hadn't occurred to me, possibly because I'm more familiar with **ring around".. As with Kate, I see the great majority of sites supporting that understanding, with a few exceptions.  https://onlineteachersuk.com/phrasal-verbs-call/

Comment: ***round, around, by, in,...*** - there are a number of alternative prepositions acceptable in the cited context, and it's not obvious to me that *any* choice makes any difference to the meaning.

Comment: @RonaldSole: I think maybe your NGram results are being distorted by "false positives" along the lines *I'll call around 5 o'clock* = *[I will phone you] **...at about** 5 o'clock*. Personally I think ***to call round*** works better than ***to call around*** for ***to stop by, visit briefly***, and there seem to be far more hits in Google Books for ***call round tonight*** than for the same sequence with ***around***.

Answer (score 2):

As a speaker of American English I would not hear those sentences as identical.

> "I'll call round and see you on my way home."

suggests to me that I will stop by your house on my way home (perhaps from school, or after running some errands).

> "I'll call around and see you on my way home."

suggests that I will be visiting people all afternoon (calling around) and will make your house my last stop on my way home.

I'm not claiming any dictionary authority for this. It's just how the sentences sound to me.
In context they could reasonably mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Q. “I'll call round and see you on my way home.” Can we replace 'round' with 'around'?

---

a. **Yes**. *In this particular case the two words "around" and "round" are interchangeable*.

**Note** *Round & Around both have several definitions and only in some instances are the two interchangeable*.

**The Definition of 'call around' as relating to a telephone call is not relevant** to your title question, because *you have already defined that* round and around are being *used in the context of visiting someone* on your way home. However there maybe some debate on whether or not the use of "round" is standard UK English Although in my region it is commonly used.

---

Ref [**Cambridge English Dictionary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/around)  **Grammar**

**Around or round?**
Around and round are prepositions or adverbs. We use around and round when we refer to movements in circles or **from one place to another. Around and round can both be used**. Around is more common in American English. Round is a little more common in speaking: …

---

**round** preposition, adverb (DIRECTION); **in a particular direction**:

You must come round (to my house) sometime soon.

UK not standard We're going round (= to) the pub for a quick drink.

---

**around**; preposition, adverb (*UK also round*) (**IN THIS DIRECTION**)

All ref C.E.D.

---

**Note regarding** **your P.S**. I believe this should be a separate question. This reference has a potential 4 answers needing to be explained for each language. Are you referring to the **Noun or the verb** for call relating to visit and the same relating to telephone? or are you referring to both the verb and the noun?

PS. I feel In BrE, "call around" has two meanings 1. visit 2. make phone calls and in AmE "call around" is making phone calls and both in BrE and AmE "call round" is visit.